# XML vs. setImageDrawable/setImageBitmap

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drawable

It is advantageous in my application if I preload certain images. I do this correctly, in AsyncTask, as it is written in the official documentation. But I have a problem/question about when they should be set.

I'll show code snippets. Note that it's simplified (their interoperability is better in my real code, it checks for nulls, etc.).

Let's see the original (non-preloaded) version first:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewMyGraphicalImageElement"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
    android:src="@drawable/my_graphical_element" >
</ImageView>
```

The preloaded version has the following XML (notice that the src attribute is missing):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewMyGraphicalImageElement"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop">
</ImageView>
```

And a snippet from the preload code:

```
sBitmap = bitmapBitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_graphical_element, options); 
// 'sBitmap' is a Bitmap reference, while 'options' is BitmapFactory.Options
```

Finally, the place where I set it:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
...
ImageView imageViewMyGraphicalImageElement= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewMyGraphicalImageElement);
imageViewMyGraphicalImageElement.setImageBitmap(sBitmap);
```

Question:
Obviously, the xml-based solution knows about the image **before** setContentView(...) is called. The preload version sets the image **after** that call. Is there any difference? Can some autoscaling or other things done by the system be skipped due to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference at all. You can consider that all the `ImageView` constructor does with the `android:src` attribute is call `setImageResource`.

**Update:** Actually it uses `setImageDrawable`, this is the actual code for `ImageView` constructor taking attributes:

```
    Drawable d = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.ImageView_src);
    if (d != null) {
        setImageDrawable(d);
    }
```

Reference: [ImageView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java)

Comment: I understand, but the difference in my code is that the ImageView constructor (i.e. the **XML-based solution**) is called before (or during?) setContentView. In the programmatic solution, I call setImageDrawable (or setImageBitmap -- both worked for me) **after** setContentView().
I know that Android does auto-scaling and other stuff with bitmaps and the layout, so I just wonder which of those are skipped due to the late call to setImageDrawable/setImageBitmap.

Comment: @Thomas Calc: If you check the code, you will see that all the `setImage` variants do the _auto-scaling and other stuff_ themselves. No functionality will be skipped.

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote up an article for this. Wish to be able to answer your question.

https://plus.google.com/112740367348600290235/posts/VNAfFLDcKrw

`ImageView` has 4 APIs to specify the image. Which one to use? What is the difference?

1. setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)
2. setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
3. setImageResource(int resId)
4. setImageURI(URI uri)

`ImageView`, by the name, is used to display an image. But what is a image? A `Bitmap` is-a image, not hard to understand and we use `setImageBitmap` for that purpose. However, internally, the `ImageView` has-a `Drawable` but not a `Bitmap` and that is what `setImageDrawable` for. When you call `setImageBitmap`, internally, first the bitmap will be wrapped to `BitmapDrawable`, which IS-A `Drawable`, and then call `setImageDrawable`.

Here is the code.

```
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bm));
}
```

So, what about the 3 and 4 API?

You should already know that that are bunches of ways to create a bitmap, from a file path, from the Uri, or from the resource file.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName)
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Inputstream)
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resource res, int id)  
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte[] data)
```

Aware of this, it is easy to understand `setImageResource`/`setImageUri` is just same as `setImageBitmap`.

To sum up, `setImageDrawable` is the primitive function other APIs rely on. The other 3 are just helper methods making you write less code.

In addition, it is very important to keep in mind that `ImageView` actually has-a `Drawable`, which not necessarily to be a `BitmapDrawable`! You could set any `Drawable` to the Image view.

Besides setting the `Drawable` through Java API, you could also using XML attribution to set the source `Drawable` for `ImageView`. See example below. Note that the shape could be either an image file (.png, .jpg, .bmp) or xml file.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:src="@drawable/shape"/>
```

shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF" android:angle="270"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: @nhahtdh ,Thanks for your clearing up the format and making it more readable!